# Running a Flask app within a Docker container results in "./boot.sh: 2: exec: gunicorn: not found"

Tags: python, docker, flask, gunicorn

I am trying to create a Flask app running within a Docker container but I have some complex dependencies so I am building from this image https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda/.

**I build the image** *(goes fine... environment works...)*:

```
docker build -t my_image:latest .
```

**Then try to run it**

```
docker run --name my_image -p 80:5000 --rm my_image:latest
```

**I get this error:**

```
./boot.sh: 2: exec: gunicorn: not found
```

Here is my directory I am building from:

```
my_template
--api.py
--boot.sh
--environment.yml
--Dockerfile
```

I have a very simple flask app.
`api.py`

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def hello_world():
    return jsonify({'message': 'Hello World'})

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def test():
    return jsonify({'test': 'test'})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True) # remember to set debug to False
```

`environment.yml` is as follows:

```
name: ox
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  {---OMITTED FOR BREVITY---}
prefix: /home/me/anaconda3/envs/ox
```

`Dockerfile` is as follows:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda:latest

WORKDIR /home/conda_flask_docker

COPY environment.yml ./
COPY api.py ./
COPY boot.sh ./

RUN chmod +x boot.sh

RUN conda env create -f environment.yml

RUN echo "source activate ox" > ~/.bashrc
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/ox/bin:$PATH

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["./boot.sh"]
```

And... `boot.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
exec gunicorn -b :5000 --access-logfile - --error-logfile - api:app
```

Comment: Solved. I needed to add 
```
 - flask=1.1.2=pyh9f0ad1d_0  
  - gunicorn=20.0.4=py38h32f6830_1
```
to dependencies in `environment.yml`

Comment: Yes! I'd be glad to!

Answer (score 0):

Solved this on my own...

I needed to add

```
 - flask=1.1.2=pyh9f0ad1d_0 
 - gunicorn=20.0.4=py38h32f6830_1
```

to the `dependencies` section of environment.yml. I had used `conda env export > environment.yml` to build my `environment.yml` BEFORE I had added Flask and gunicorn.

If that doesn't do it, adding gunicorn via `RUN` command in the Dockerfile should do.